# Where to install Anaconda?

Tags: software-installation, python, anaconda

I'm using SSD for / and HDD for /home and /var.

I want to use Anaconda on SSD because I think it's faster.

I'm installing Anaconda and asked where to install.

Where do I install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you should install it somewhere beneath `/`, excluding the mountpoints `/home` and `/var`.

A good candidate would be `/opt/anaconda/<version>`, which opens the opportunity to install different versions of `anaconda`.

Assuming you are talking about Python Anaconda, you then have to call `python` with the full path

```
/opt/anaconda/<version>/bin/python
```

or extend your `PATH` variable. E.g. add the line as follows in your `~/.bashrc`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/anaconda/<version>/bin
```

Please not that `<version>` has to be replace with an actual number like `2.7' or whatever makes sense to you.

Comment: You can't install anaconda to /opt/ because the installer doesn't have permissions. You can run the installer with 'sudo bash ...anaconda...sh'. But that opens up a whole other can of worms.

Comment: @markling: I was assuming that basic knowledge about write permissions on paths like `/opt` is a well known thing and that users can either add `sudo` to the installer or just install it as user `root`. What other *can of worms*  would that open installing Python Anaconda into a subpath of `/opt`?

Comment: Oh a lot of water has passed under the bridge yesterday. I opened the can, it was seething with worms. I stuck my hand in and felt around blindly for a bit, but found only puzzle pieces and lots and lots of slime. In the end - and I did give it a fair shot - I just let the installer put Anaconda where it really wanted to, which was /home. I must admit, I much prefer your suggestion.